# eclipse jetty plugin : 'java.lang.String org.eclipse.m2e.core.embedder.ArtifactKey.groupId()'

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jetty

I updated my eclipse jetty plugin, but after that i not able to run my application, Getting an popup having message.
An internal error occurred during: "Launching application_name".
'java.lang.String org.eclipse.m2e.core.embedder.ArtifactKey.groupId()'

[image]

Please suggest if anybody have any solution.

Comment: Updated it from what to what? On what Eclipse version? With what version of M2E (considering it's the only thing mentioned in the Details)?

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. Please also tell how to reproduce your issue (is this a _Maven Build_ launch configuration to run a `pom.xml` file?).